# How to keep android parent view stay on position when keyboard appears?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-softkeyboard

How to make my layout stay on position, when keyboard appears?
Whenever android soft keyboard appears layout view push to up

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) Android developer guide,

"adjustPan"

The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

So add this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" > </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a Dummy layout below your layout with the width and height of your preference and Set the visibility of the Dummy layout to invisible.